# How to add date to my hbase snapshot

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to take a backup of my hbase tables on a daily basis, how do i include date and time in my hbase snapshot? i want my snapshot in this format - 'tablename-dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss'. If anyone has a shell script please share

Answer (score 1):

Use this to create suffix you need

```
hadoop@my-hadoop:~$ suffix=$(date) # create whatever format you need
hadoop@my-hadoop:~$ echo "suffix is ${suffix}"
```

Use this to create snapshot

```
hadoop@my-hadoop:~$ echo "snapshot 'myTable', 'myTable-${suffix}'" | hbase shell
```